# Python List Index problem with time data from excel

Tags: python, list

My code is as follows

```py
import openpyxl

l = list()
x = 0
filename = 'E:/Arsh/Bus_Timetable.xlsx'

# opening the xlsx file
xlsx = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename)

# opening the active sheet
sheet = xlsx.active

# getting the data from the sheet
data = sheet.rows

# putting data in the list
for row in data:
    l.append(row)

# accessing 2 dimensional list
for i in range(len(l)):
    btime = str(l[i][0].value)  # incoming value 00:17:00
    btime = btime.split(':') 
    print(btime)  # this is printing ['00', '17', '00'] i.e. **there are 3 values in the list**
    print(btime[0])  # this is printing 00
    print(btime[1])  # this is generating error "list index out of range" There are 3 values why the error???
```

Excel file has about 100 rows and 3 columns, first column is time format. I am storing all the data in a list. When I access the 2 dimensional list in the loop as in the code, though list has 3 values I'm not able to access the second value as in code `btime[1]`. I'm new to Python and really clueless as when list length is 3 why I'm not able to access the second value.

Comment: Can you show us backtrace of it?

Comment: What are you trying to solve. Do you want to get the time values from the first column (00:17:00) and then split the time value into hours minutes seconds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to split the time, load the time from the excel sheet and convert it to a time object.

Also I removed some lines where you might be duplicating data

```
import openpyxl
import time

## opening the xlsx file
filename = 'E:/Arsh/Bus_Timetable.xlsx'
xlsx = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename)

## opening the active sheet
sheet = xlsx.active

#Access each row containing a list of cells
for row in sheet.rows:
    if row[0].row == 1: continue # Skip header row, if you dont have a header row you can remove this
    btime = time.strptime(str(row[0].value), "%H:%M:%S")
    print("Hour: {} Minute: {} Second: {}".format(btime.tm_hour,btime.tm_min,btime.tm_sec))
```

Comment: Thanks, this works excellent, I agree my code has lot of duplication but it is a learning exercise and I still wonder what I am doing wrong with the list and why I couldn't access btime[1] when it has 3 values.

Comment: Please accept the answer if it helped. Without a backtrace it is difficult to understand why in this case it did not work, as there should be a value at index 1.